# Decrypting and mounting Windows Bitlocker drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, encryption

I have a system that is dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
I have some partitions that Win10 automatically has bitlocker enabled, therefore i cannot read or write from Ubuntu.

I followed this guide to try to decrypt and mount the drives:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-mount-bitlocker-encrypted.html

Under windows, i have managed to find my Bitlocker key, let's say it's this:

```
123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123
```

And let's assume that the encrypted partition is

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2
```

I have created these two directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlocker
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlockermount
```

I therefore issued this command to decrypt the drive:

```
sudo dislocker /dev/nvme0n1p2 -u 123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123-123123 -- /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

But i get this error:

```
[CRITICAL] None of the provided decryption mean is decrypting the keys. Abort.
[CRITICAL] Unable to grab VMK or FVEK. Abort.
```

I also tried supplying the password without the '-'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -u flag instead of -p,  for recovery_password vs user_password. That worked for me. I believe the 48-digit number that's auto-stored in your MS account is the recovery key. Also, with hyphens.